# Complex gaussian random variable

Tags: digital-communications, statistics, random-process

In my work i need to generate circularly symmetric complex gaussian random variables with **non zero mean and certain variance in matlab.**

I know the command for generating in case of zero mean , but how to do it for non-zero mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer and hint: Just add the mean to expression of zero mean random variable. Along with this scale the expression for unit variance gaussian with the standard deviation of the required variance. You would now have non zero mean gaussian RV with given variance

Comment: Yes got it....understood too